# TFS: What does Triage mean?

Tags: team-foundation-server, task

So I'm installing TFS for our developers to use, and I'm supposed to be the expert on this TFS thing since I'm the one that suggested we get it, but I don't know the answers to some of their questions, Maybe someone on here can tell me this one:

1) What does Triage mean in relation to Team foundation server?  It has the following options:

1. Info Received
2. More Info
3. Pending
4. Triaged

2) What do each of the options mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's intended to identify that those other items have not been set. Some organizations may have a person responsible for setting priority, classification, etc... Triaged would indicate to a developer that those items have been properly evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a TFS expert, but I would assume, in this context, that "triaged" means much the same as it does in a medical sense:  the patient/problem has been classified, prioritized, and queued.

Comment: How do the options pertain to its priority, classification, or queue?  Especially since there are already fields called Priority, Classification, and Importance.

Answer (score 0):

I consider them as follow:

**Pending**:It means the work item is waiting for a decision.(for example: the bug is waiting for decision on whether or not to fix it.)

**More Info**: It means person needs more info to make a decision.(I've read from a source:The owner of the work item is supposed to provide the additional info and reset the triage state to pending.)

**Info Received**: It means all the information for the work item has been received.

**Triaged**: It means a decision has been made.